# Error while starting dmgr of websphere in Solaris

Tags: websphere, web-deployment, solaris, websphere-7, was

Hi I tried the below command to start the dmgr.

```
~Websphere/Appserver/profiles/CORPDWAS70DepMgr/bin

$ ./startManagaer.sh
```

I got the below error.

> ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/CORPDWAS70DepMgr/logs/dmgr/startServer.log
>   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the CORPDWAS70DepMgr profile
>   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: dmgr
>   ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
>   ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log,
>   SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/CORPDWAS70DepMgr/logs/dmgr
>   should contain failure information.

I opened the systemout.log

[image]

I am unable to understand the error.
Please help.

Comment: You need to check the server log files (as noted in the "SystemOut.log and other log files under ... should contain failure information" part of the message) in order to see why the startup failed. The output you shared is from the launcher process, which only is able to tell that the server process did not start, not why it failed.

Comment: That picture is just the file header. Open the file and read through it, looking for exception or error messages (especially near the end of the file, as a fatal exception is likely to occur shortly before the process ends). Usually the errors will at least attempt useful messages, so ideally you'll be able to interpret what is preventing the server from starting.